# Are open protocols compatible with old MAP versions

Tags: acoustic-telemetry

I am interested in using the new open protocols in acoustic telemetry and wanted to know if they are comparable with older MAP versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Open Protocols (OPi and OPs) are currently not compatible with older MAP versions.
As mentioned by Kim B. Some older protocols as R64K are compatible up to MAP 114.
The overview of which protocols are compatible across manufacturers can help to explain: https://www.europeantrackingnetwork.org/en/compatibility-tag-protocols

Answer (score 2):

The new open protocols are compatible with older MAP versions (up to MAP114 on the R64K codeset), but NOT the newer version (MAP115) which is encrypted. To find our more, you can visit the European Tracking Network website (https://www.europeantrackingnetwork.org/en/open-protocol); they have some pretty good explanations of what codesets are compatible with each other!

Answer (score 0):

There are also issues with using the older protocols that are cross-compatible with MAP114 (InnovaSea). We have used S256 tags in an array with multiple manufacturer's receivers and have tons of false detections that make the animal movements extremely challenging to resolve. The results from OPi and OPs testing suggest that this issue can be resolved with the new protocols to improve interoperability!

Answer (score 0):

But both R64K and the two new OPi and OPs are all compatible on other manufacturers protocols. I suggest you look up those (Thelma, Lotek and Sonotronics).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).